# How to place sizes in order

Tags: dropdown-attribute

We sell clothing and have configurable products that consist of simple products with sizes S,M,L,XL etc.

When we choose a product and click on the size dropdown the sizes turn up in random order:

M
XS
L
S

How can we put them in ascending order?
XS
S
M
L

Thanks,

Stefania

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, Configurable products use the attributes, in your case this is `size` attribute.

Find your attribute inside **Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes**

Now in manage options give it's position. [image]